# How fill NULLs with previous value in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following table

[image]

There are some NULL values in `price` column, which I want to replace with the previous date value (date is `manual_date`). Additionally, `price` column is calculated on different dates (`calculation_table`), so the nulls should be filled based on this group filter.
The `final output` should show values similar to `output_price`.
I found [here](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/TimeSeries/NullValuesTimeSeries.htm?tocpath=Analyzing%20Data%7CTime%20Series%20Analytics%7C_____2) a code that does the same thing, however, I could not figure out how to do it with my data (one of the error says I have not ts in `(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY ts)`. This is true, but in the website, there is also no ts specified + I tried to replace it ts with manual_date)

I tried following code for my data

```
select manual_date,TS_FIRST_VALUE(price, 'const') output_price
from MYDATA
TIMESERIES manual_date AS '1 month' 
OVER(PARTITION BY calculation_date ORDER BY ts)  --tried also ORDER BY manual_date
```

Comment: Please clarify how you are defining "previous".

Answer (score 0):

Vertical supports `IGNORE NULLS` on `last_value()`.  So you can use:

```
last_value(price ignore nulls) over (
    order by manual_date
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
   ) as output_price
```

Comment: yes, it is working if there is only one `calculation_date`. However, if the `calculation_date` are in a different order (like 04.01.2021, 05.11.2020, 05.11.2020, 04.01.2021 ...) then the first 05.11.2020 value (if it is missing) can become the previous 04.01.2021 value. If in the beginning I order the data by `calculation_date,manual_date`, will it solve the problem? or there should be a use kind of partition by statements?

Comment: @PriitMets . . . You have to use the column or columns that define "previous".    Note that this uses `manual_date`, not `calculation_date`, because that is the only obvious such column in your question.

Comment: How can I also add `calculation_date` to be a column that identifies previous values? Because calculation_date shows 2 different groups and these two groups have different values for the same `manual_date` and if take previous value based only on `manual_date`  then values for these two groups could be wrong